# "normalizing" defining a resource for a restful api

Tags: rest

So I'm creating a service using webapi and I'm attempting to adhere to rest as much as i can while still providing functionality that makes sense...

Say i have restaurants which have locations. Each location has an address but also has its own data like location name and phone number.

Should i have 1 /location/ endpoint and expose each location and always include the address in each http operation or should i also have a /location/{id}/address/ endpoint and force the caller to make both calls if they also want this address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's up to you. How do you defined the representation for the `Location` resource? How expensive is it for you to return all addresses for all clients requesting the parent resource? How useful is for the clients to get that information in a single step? Do you expect them to cache information? A decision depends on the answer to questions like those.

In my APIs I try to use something I call the Zoom Protocol, which allows clients to decide that. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26665301/rest-api-using-get-params/26666892#26666892) for more details on that.